# Text cursor scrolling me as I am pressing arrow keys

Tags: keyboard, text-cursor

I am currently working on Windows 10.  When I press the regular direction keys on my keyboard, my cursor moves in the direction I am pressing. I would like my cursor not to move when I press the direction keys.  How can I stop this behavior?

I have tried various methods like rebooting, checking mouse function but all in vain. I know this question has been asked before but like in that it was given to close microsoft paint but in my case only chrome is opened. So can u please suggest some methods to stop this behavior?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjgFF.png)

Comment: The direction keys on my keyboard(s) have zero impact on the mouse function.  Do you have a special keyboard?  Have you tried an upgraded Mouse Driver?

Comment: @John No I don't have any special keyboard and my mouse driver is updated to the latest version.

Comment: Scrolling a web page in Chrome with the arrow keys is normal behavior if the cursor focus in not in a actual text field.  What are you trying to do in Chrome with the arrow keys? Have you observed this behavior in other apps?

Comment: if you will click on image description here in the question you can see that I opened a random chrome page. Now I wanted to go down so I pressed down key but now the text cursor is going down and it takes time and frustrates  me. Before Search only for regr you can see the text cursor. What I want is that when I click the down button the page should go down not the text cursor neither the text cursor should come

Comment: Try using the Page Down key to move the window down instead of the down arrow key when the text cursor is in a text field.  It might be abbreviated to PgDn on your keyboard.  It's near PgUp, Home and End.

Comment: @Blaelph thanks that helps if you can write this comment as an answer i would accept it. Just can you tell that since PgDn scrolls the page down very quickly so can i decrease the speed of PgDn function key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome, you can use the <kbd>PgDn</kbd> key to scroll the page if the text cursor is in a text field, preventing you from scrolling the page with the <kbd>ArrowDown</kbd> key.

Answer (score 2):

Because the above didnt solve it this for me, here's my solution: this is happening because you clicked F7 at some point and turned on caret browsing.

Press F7 again to disable caret browsing and the problem will go away.

Comment: This is the correct answer. By mistake I pressed F7 and facing the problem. Thanks to you, solved my problem scrolling webpage.